# ASP.Net web Projects designing

Tags: asp.net

I have few questions related to asp .net development. can anyone answer my questions and help me.

how many projects does visual studio support? currently, we are have 60 projects including all library projects? is it good to continuously add projects to the single solution? does this effect anything?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware that you have a hard limit to the amount of projects. *Might* be just a question of computer resources (memory to handle such a big solution and related activities?). Not certain about this though since haven't found authorative references

In any case this amount of projects indicates a poor design of the solution. It's really hard to work with such a big structure, we could consider this an anti-pattern.

I recommend you to spend some time with your team to apply some refactoring:

- Do you have "commom" projects that you can build and just reference dll?
- Can you group projects together?
- Can you group independent projects into a separated solution? Maybe you have a console application and a web application in the same solution and they have compontent used by only one of them.

Comment: ours is a product based company and we have 25 different products under the same solution. also, I have 25 libraries for 25 projects. can I merge all the libraries into one single library project. if I do so what will happen?

Comment: @pramodkumar: I don't know if you can merge all libraries into a single one. there is no silver bullet answer. There is no limitation on the tool, it's a question of your project design. My suggestion is start separating those 25 products into separated solutions

Comment: The main problem with the solution you gave is, for each and every client the no.of accessible products will be different.if one client needs all the projects we are providing access from the database. and at the same time we are restricting the unwanted modules.